# How to get data of a select option tag into a php variable before submitting pure php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table that shows a list of students. The data is shown using a foreach loop.
Now inside the table, I have a column to store the attendance which specifies whether a student is present or absent. I put the present and absent inside a select tag in HTML.
as shown below:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>
          <select name="att">
             <option value="1">Present</option>
             <option value="0">Absent</option>
          </select>  
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

Now I want to take the attendance and update related rows inside the table.
How to get values of IDs and atts to pass through php to the database?
I tried to get the values inside php array and send it but how to get the value from the select tag inside an array I have no idea.
If possible please provide the code.

Comment: What you tried so far? || Search on `google` you  get idea!

Comment: Share your code here, all you tried so far in `php` || Update your post

Answer (score -1):

just like this

```
$att =$_POST['att'];
```

Comment: please look at [answer]